# PHP variable appended by arbitrarily issuing variable name

Tags: php

I don't know if this is good place to ask such a questions, but I want to understand how PHP variables work. As we all know that we can add a variable to another variable like this:

```
$abc = "Some Text"
$ab_apnd = "{$abc} missing*";
echo $ab_apnd;
```

Then this will show output like:

> Some Text missing*

But the question here is when I pass the same text over `$_POST` it doesn't work.

```
# $_POST['abc'] = "{$abc}" // through a form not from php code //
$abc = "Some Text";
$ab_apnd = $_POST['abc'] . " missing*";
echo $ab_apnd;
```

Now this will show an output like this:

> {abc} missing*;

I will be thankful if you teach me why this happens! Thank you.

Comment: try `$$_POST['abc']`, though this is very unsafe todo in a real app. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone now its blank.

Comment: strange, since php treats post variables as strings, the result would most likely be:  `{$abc} missing*`.

Comment: @leo_ap but "{$abc}" is also treated like text in the first code right? and it works

Comment: No, php interpreter is able to understand that you are using a variable inside a quoted string. Imagine if it do the same to posts, one would never be able to submit a single dollar sign in any form input. I dont know the exactly reason, but i think this is a security issue.

Comment: @leo_ap Thanks , i got it know

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Would `$$_POST['abc']}` be treated as `${$_POST['abc']}`, or as `${$_POST}['abc']`?.... but you're right that it's  unsafe, and difficult for other people to understand what's going on when reading that code

Comment: For a thorough overview of how PHP variables work, please check out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use a variable value as a variable name. You can use eval function for this.

```
<form action="" method=post>    
   <input type='text' name="abc">
   <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php    
  $abc = "Some Text";    
  eval('$ab_apnd ="' . $_POST['abc'] . ' missing*";');   
  echo $ab_apnd; 
?>
```

Comment: why it cant be achieved with simple method like i used ?

Comment: Because you want to change codes with a variable content. Variable contents move data, but not codes. Actually this is the base structure logic for programming. If you want to use this content as code you have to tell this to the programming language's compiler/interpreter. Eval function doing that.

Comment: @lawrence the british should consider this before invading India. everything started there. :)

Comment: To me that saying means, "your code is open and I could own your server if I found it.".. like the saying "eval is evil" the classical meaning of the phrase... not what you think

Comment: Ok, my mistake. There some memes, I'm confused. Yes eval is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

why make this so complicated:

```
<?php
  $_POST['abc']= "some text";   
  $ab_apnd = $_POST['abc'] . ' missing*';
  echo $ab_apnd;
?>
```